# Simple Regular Expression Help in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Not sure if it is possible, I need to improve my RegExp. I have the following:

```
\b(?:http|https)://www\.domain\.co\.za/.*
```

It is fine for all my purpases except I would like it to also validate for:

```
http://www.domain.co.za (No Backslash at the end)
```

But should NOT validate for:

```
http://www.domain.co.zaaaaa
```

And then This Expression:

```
\b(?:https?)://[.0-9a-z-]*domain\.co\.za
```

To validate for (Currently Working)

```
http://domain.co.za
http://sub1.domain.co.za
http://wwww.domain.co.za
```

But it should NOT validate for:

```
http://abcdomain.co.za
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty easy:

```
\b(?:http|https)://www\.domain\.co\.za/?\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bN9wA3/1)

`.*` is useless since it always matches, I just removed it, made the `/` optional and inserted a `\b`.

The second case is similar:

```
\b(?:https?)://[.0-9a-z-]*\bdomain\.co\.za
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQ4dB2/1)

Just use that magic `\b` :)

Or, if you want a more strict pattern, this would be better:

```
\b(?:https?)://(?>[0-9a-z-]+\.)*domain\.co\.za
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQ4dB2/2)

because it enforces runs of characters separated by `.` for the subdomains. The atomic group (`(?>`...`)`) is here to avoid [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).